# Add Multiple jlabels in ScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlabel

I have a scrollpane in which i want to add multiple jlabel. In jTextField1 user enters the no Between 1-10 (here no. tells how many jlabels have to be added) and accordingly jlabels will be added in scroll pane.

Can anyone tell me how can I do this.

```
int x=jTextField1.getText;
    JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel();
    mainpanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainpanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    this.add(mainpanel);

    JPanel rightpanel = new JPanel();
    rightpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        rightpanel.add(new JLabel("Label " + i));
    }
    mainpanel.add(new JLabel("Left label"));
    mainpanel.add(new JScrollPane(rightpanel));
```

This code is not working. Although it is working when we do the same thing in another jFrame i.e.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Labels");

    JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel();
    mainpanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainpanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    frame.add(mainpanel);

    JPanel rightpanel = new JPanel();
    rightpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        rightpanel.add(new JLabel("Label " + i));
    }
    mainpanel.add(new JLabel("Left label"));
    mainpanel.add(new JScrollPane(rightpanel));
    frame.setSize(500, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

However, i want to do it in the same jFrame.

Answer (score 5):

- You don't add JLabels directly to a JScrollPane.
- But you can add them to a JPanel that is held by the JScrollPane's JViewport (be sure to go through the [JScollPane tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)). Often that JPanel will use a GridLayout, and you add the JLabels by simply calling `add(...)` on the JPanel, and then calling `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the JPanel after all components have been added
- But having said that, it sounds as if you're far better off using a JList held by a JScrollPane and adding items to your JList. Please check the [JList tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for details on how to use this.

For a more detailed answer, you will want to ask a more detailed question including code, preferably an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: *"I have edited my Question"*  You perhaps should have read the linked document on the SSCCE first. The edit includes uncompilable code snippets, not an SSCCE.

Comment: @AmitSinghGour: yep, create and post your sscce. But regardless, look at the JList tutorial link that I've posted above since that looks to hold your most straightforward solution.